# Parsing out a hidden field inside iframe using HtmlAgilityPack .NET

Tags: c#, forms, iframe, hidden, html-agility-pack

I'm having problems picking out data I need that's inside an iframe form. Is it even possible using HtmlAgilityPack? Here's a screenshot using Firebug so it's easier for you guys to see.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftt84.jpg

I need to parse out the post_form_id. I've tried

```
var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@type='hidden' and @name='post_form_id']")
        .Attributes["value"].Value;
```

but obviously won't work because it's inside the iframe form. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would

1. Use the HTMLAglityPack to find the iframe location
2. Use the System.URI class find the absolute link of the iframe page
3. Open this iframe page
4. Use HTMLAglityPack again on the iframe page to find the required information

Comment: +1 - Since the content of an `IFrame` is a separate document, it needs to be loaded separately.